# Stack up dynamic number of divs vertically then on right w. css/js

Tags: jquery, html, css

I load dynamic number of divs ( variable height ) into parent div. 
I'd need to load them as follows:

```
----parent div ------
-div1-  -div5-
-div2-  -div6-
-div3-  -div7-
-div4-  -div8-
---------------------
```

When I use float:left they stack up the way i don't want:

```
-div1- -div2-
-div3- -div4-
-div5- -div6-
```

Any ideas? Can I use js to detect overflowing div?

Comment: You add add two containers in parent div as  .left and .right and while inserting the even or odd divs , u can consider which container to put into , like append all even divs in .left and odd divs in .right .

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/yGgmN/)***

Add another div in there to emulate the columns

```
----parent div ------
--sub-- | --sub--
 -div1- | -div5-
 -div2- | -div6-
 -div3- | -div7-
 -div4- | -div8-
------- | -------
---------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you are targeting only modern browsers

A [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox) is perfect for this:

**HTML** :

```
<div class="parentDiv"></div>
```

**CSS**: (Works for chrome. Use relevant prefixes `-ms -moz -o` as required)

```
.parentDiv{
    display:-webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap; 
    width : 60px;
    height: 100px
}
.parentDiv div{
    width:20px;
    height:24px;
}
```

**JS / JQUERY**:

```
$(function() {       
    for(var i=1; i<7; i++)  $(".parentDiv").append($("<div>").text("div"+i));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CBnYb/)

Comment: Hm flexbox, haven't heard of that so that is cool to see something new to me. Just for reference, here are the environments which support it: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: It's introduced with HTML5. It will be supported in HTML5 complaint browsers only...

Comment: Some poor souls still have to support older browsers :P Just trying to be transparent.

Comment: True. Edited my answer to remind this. :) thanks